# R for data science programming questions

Tags: r

How could I use If expressions rather than result[result==Inf] ?

I want to change this code using If expressions.

```
x=c(1:10,Inf,-Inf)
rescale01 <- function(x) {
rng <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)
y <- (x - rng[1]) / (rng[2] - rng[1])
y[y == -Inf] <- 0
y[y == Inf] <- 1
y
}
```

I tried it, but I don't know what's wrong.
Please help!
This is a code I tried.

```
x=c(1:10,Inf,-Inf)
rescale01=function(x){
rng=range(x, na.rm=T, finite=T)
result=(x-rng[1])/(rng[2]-rng[1])
if (result==Inf){
Inf=1
} 
if (result==-Inf){
-Inf=-1
}
else {
print(result)
}
}
```

Comment: Try using  'is.Infinite' rather than double equal to.

Comment: @PKumar, ````ìs.infinite()```` doesn't work if you want ````Inf```` to be replaced with 1 and ````-Inf```` to be replaced with -1, as OP does

Comment: @Mr.Rlover, It will if you do something like this: `is.infinite(x) & sign(x) == -1` for negatives and `is.infinite(x) & sign(x) == 1` for positives

Comment: I don't understand the way you suggested. Could you write a code for mee?

Answer (score 1):

The `if(x==Inf) {} else {}` structure doesn't work because `if` only takes a vector of length one that will be used for comparison. So if you supply a vector of length greater than one, the other values are ignored.

Use `ifelse()` since it's vectorised, which means that it evaluates the entire vector at once.

For your purposes, you need a nested `ifelse()` since you have two `if` statements.

**EDIT:** Thanks to comment from @linog, we use `identical(x, Inf)` rather than `x==Inf`. Since identical is not vectorised and returns a single value, `TRUE` or `FALSE`, we use `sapply` to perform the operation over the entire vector.

```r
x=c(1:10,Inf,-Inf)
rescale01=function(x){
  rng=range(x, na.rm=T, finite=T)
  result=(x-rng[1])/(rng[2]-rng[1])
  result = ifelse(sapply(result, identical, Inf), 1, ifelse(sapply(result, identical, -Inf), -1, result))
  return(result)
}

rescale01(x)
 [1]  0.0000000  0.1111111  0.2222222  0.3333333  0.4444444  0.5555556  0.6666667
 [8]  0.7777778  0.8888889  1.0000000  1.0000000 -1.0000000
```

Comment: `result==Inf` is not very safe, I would rather use `identical(result, Inf)`. Otherwise, your answer is fine